# Render back to original URL

Tags: node.js

I would like to get help regarding one situation:

I have '**user-profile-edit**' page, which also render some info from database:
[image]
[image]

But that page has several forms with different submit buttons, for example:
[image]

...and...

[image]

Which links to different authController, for example:
[image]

[image]

Now if everything is alright one of authController is render back user to '**user-profile-edit**':
[image]

Problem is that page url shows me:
[image]

...or...

[image]

So at this point I can't get my information about cities in '**user-profile-edit**' page.

How render back users to **user-profile-edit** instead of **user-profile-edit-one** or **user-profile-edit-two**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So instead render now I use:

```
req.flash('message', 'message text');
res.redirect('/user-profile-edit');
```